# DocuSign CreateAndSendEnvelope "Guid cannot be null"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm trying duplicate the sample code found here:
https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm#Sending%20Group/Create%20and%20Send.htm

I copied the C# code to build the envelope and only adjusted for my environment.. sample file, email address etc. When I execute this I get the following exception:

> A processing error occurred: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The
>   request contained at least one invalid parameter. Guid cannot be null.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   SampleApp.DSAPIService.DSAPIServiceSoap.CreateAndSendEnvelope(Envelope
>   Envelope)

Has anyone seen this issue?  I've looked over the Envelope, Recipient, Document, and Tab types on the API reference and I don't see any field that is a guid.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  It looks like I missed setting up the Envelope.AccountId field.